# How can I change ZSH history to always use the -i option?

Tags: zsh, history

I want the output of `history` in ZSH on MacOS to always use the `-i` option to show timestamps. Can I set an option or alias to make it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alias hi='history -i'
```

Add this to the init file of your choice (most likely `.zshrc`).